# AFWall+ not blocking consistently

Tags: rooting, security, firewall, systemless-root, iptables

I'm running a rooted pixel 3 (Magisk) with the "liboemcrypt disabler" module for running Netflix, Magisk Hide and the dg.db edit to disable attestation for running Google Pay.

The firewall will work sometimes after applying the rules a bunch or after a restart, but it doesn't work about 80% of the time and works only about 20% of the time.

I have tried disabling and enabling, enabling delayed startup, disabling LAN and toggling IPV6 (found a few posts about the same issue and those were the suggested fixes).

Here is my config:

https://pastebin.com/raw/2ANFnpCS

Any ideas on how to get AFWall working?

Comment: I am not very familiar with AFWall+, but you mention IPv6 and based on this info I would assume that AFWAll/iptables resolves the network addresses to different IPs. For cloud hosted services the IP changes often and also may differ if not the same DNS server is used. If you want to block something you should use the different approach: Instead of blocking certain sites (black listing) you should block everything and then allow only selected sites (white listing).

Comment: AFWall doesn't block connections, kernel does. AFWall just adds iptables rules. Output of `iptables -S` along with UIDs of affected apps would be more helpful to rectify your problem.

Comment: @Robert AFWall blocks apps via iptables, not IP addresses as Ifran said..

Comment: @IrfanLatif Yes you are right, I should have used more accurate language. My bad. I will connect over ADB and dump the iptables output when I'm back from the office in a few hours.

Comment: @anon, sorry but by your comment you show that you don't understand what iptables is. It is the client program used to configure the filters/firewall rules in the kernel and the firewall works on IP level (hence it block IP addresses). Therefore what Irfan wrote is very accurate.

Comment: @Robert iptables has the ability to block by UID tho, correct?

Comment: @Robert I just verified by looking at the source of afwall+, and it indeed block by app uid, not IP address.